# Time to move along a path?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, time

Let's say I have an arbitrary path from point $A$ to point $B$. A particle moves from $A$ to $B$ under the influence of gravity but also impeded by a frictional force $\vec{F_\mu}$. The gravitational field does work on the particle such that 
$$
\int_a^c{\vec{F_g} \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{x}}
~=~ W
~=~ \Delta T
\tag{1}
\,,$$ and on the other side because the frictional force is always parallel to the path,
$$
\int_a^c {\vec{F_\mu}} \, \mathrm{d}\vec{x}
~=~ -W
\,.$$
So should it not be true that
$$
\int_a^x \left(\vec{F_g} \cdot \hat{T}-\vec{F_\mu}\right) \, \mathrm{d}x
~=~ \Delta T
\tag{2}
$$
is the change in kinetic energy between points $a$ and $x$ on the path? In that case, by incorporation of arclength and rearranging the kinetic energy to be in terms of velocity is it not true that
$$
\Delta t
~=~ \int\limits_a^b{\sqrt{\frac{1+{y'}^{2}}{\vec{F_g} \cdot \hat{T}-\vec{F_\mu}}}} \, \mathrm{d}x
\tag{3}
\,,$$(integrating the $t=d/s$ equation essentially)? If this is the case, then for the path $y=-x+10$, ${y'}^2 = 1$, so
$$
\Delta t
~=~ \int\limits_0^{10}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\frac{F_g\sqrt{2}}{2}}} \, \mathrm{d}x
~=~ \int\limits_0^{10}{\sqrt{\frac{4}{\sqrt{2}F_g}} \, \mathrm{d}x}
~=~ 5.3723 \, \mathrm{s}
\tag{4}
\,.$$

This blatantly conflicts with my HS level physics answer of $2.02 \, \mathrm{s} ,$ which (while hastily obtained) seems more plausibly the correct answer.

**Question:**  How can my first method be adapted to obtain the correct time for the movement to occur, and is it a proper method for more convoluted paths? Also please point out the probably obvious error which is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in your case is:

For conservative system (no friction )  the energy $E$ is conserved.

$E=T+U$

Thus:
$$E_i=E_f \mapsto T_i+U_i=T_f+U_f\tag 1$$

where $T$ is the kinetic energy and $U$  the potential energy. i; initial state and f; final state

with:

$T=\frac{1}{2}\,m\,\vec{v}\cdot \vec{v}$

$U=m\,g\,y(x)$

and

$\vec{v}=\frac{dx}{dt}\left[ \begin {array}{c} {1}\\  \left( {\frac 
{d}{dx}}y \left( x \right)  \right) {}\end {array} \right]
$

thus:

$$E(x,xp)=T+U=1/2\,{{\it xp}}^{2}m+1/2\, \left( {\it ys} \left( x \right)  \right) ^
{2}{{\it xp}}^{2}m+mgy \left( x \right) 
\tag 2$$

where : 
$xp=\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $ys=\frac{dy}{dx}$

for the

initial state: $x=0\,,xp=0$
and the
final state:  $x=L\,,xp=dx/dt$ we get with equations (1)

$$E_i(0,0)=E_f\left(L,\frac{dx}{dt}\right)\tag 3$$

with equation (2) we solve equation (3) for $dx/dt$ and get:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}={\frac {\sqrt {2}\sqrt { \left( 1+ \left( {\it ys} \left( L \right) 
 \right) ^{2} \right) g \left( y \left( 0 \right) -y \left( L \right) 
 \right) }}{1+ \left( {\it ys} \left( L \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
\tag 4$$

we solve equation (4) for $t(x=L)$ and get:

$$\boxed{t(x=L)=\frac{1}{2}\,{\frac {L \left( 1+ \left( {\it ys} \left( L \right)  \right) ^{2
} \right) \sqrt {2}}{\sqrt { \left( 1+ \left( {\it ys} \left( L
 \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) g \left( y \left( 0 \right) -y \left( L
 \right)  \right) }}}}
$$

your example:

$y(x)=-x+10$

$ys(x)=\frac{d y(x)}{dx}=-1$

$\rightarrow$

$$t=\frac{L}{\sqrt{g\,L}}=\frac{10}{\sqrt{9.81\,,10}}\approx 1 [s]$$

Remarks:

I) If you have a friction force, to get the time $t$   you must solve the equation of motion (numerically)  and stop the simulation when x reach the  length $L$.

II) The general description of a path is $x=x(s)$ and $y=y(s)$ where s is the path parameter (path length), but the steps to obtain the time $t$ are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain that you can't write the force as a derivative of a gradient when there exists a non-conservative force(friction here).